# Selenium gives "selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: cannot find Chrome binary" on Mac

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, selenium

Trying to get `selenium` to work with Python 3 for web scraping purposes:

```
from selenium import webdriver
chrome_path = r"/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/chromedriver"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_path)
```

I get the following error message:

> selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: cannot find Chrome binary

A similar question was addressed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43287203/selenium-gives-unknown-error-cannot-find-chrome-binary-when-running-chrome-dr), but what is baffling to me is that Chrome is already installed on my system. The other asker apparently didn't have it on their computer. I'm running latest version of Mac OS.

Comment: Which version of chrome are you using ? Please attach a screenshot of the version with your question

Comment: Version 60.0.3112.113

Comment: Which path is your chrome installed on?

Comment: File is stored at:
/Users/alex/Desktop

Answer (score 65, accepted):

The issue is that chromedriver also needs to know where chrome is. In your case it is at a non-default path. So you need to specify the complete path to the `Google Chrome` binary.

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.binary_location = "/Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome"
chrome_driver_binary = "/usr/local/bin/chromedriver"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_driver_binary, chrome_options=options)
```

Above code is what you should use

Comment: Do not miss that the path does not end with `..../chrome.app`
The path should include `contents/macos/`

Comment: If I code in Google Colab, How to get the binary location?

Comment: good day dear Tarun - many thanks: well what can i do if i am facing this issue in google-colab. Well that is a bit special i think: Can i do a workaround there too!? - see my thread here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76401453/gathering-data-from-clutch-io-some-issues-with-bs4-while-working-on-colab - look forward to hear from you. Regards

Answer (score 9):

I have met this annoying problem when I am lerning selenium. 
This is my solution: (MacOS 10.13.4)

1. uninstall my chrome
2. use homebrew to install chromedriver: `brew cask install chromedriver`
3. use homebrew to install chrome: `brew cask install google-chrome`

Thanks to homebrew now chrome and chromedriver are installed in the same folder and this problem will be automatically solved.

Comment: In 2021, just `brew install google-chrome` will do.

Comment: goof day dear joseph - many thanks: well what can i do if i am facing this issue in google-colab. Can i do a workaround there too!? - see my thread here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76401453/gathering-data-from-clutch-io-some-issues-with-bs4-while-working-on-colab - look forward to hear from you. Regards

Answer (score 7):

If anyone is getting the same error on a linux machine, then you are missing **google chrome** installation as one of the steps needed for chrome driver to work.

Follow [this link](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-install-google-chrome-on-redhat-rhel-fedora-centos-linux/) to install Google chrome on Linux.

Now, check code

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='/usr/bin/chromedriver', options=chrome_options, service_args=['--verbose', '--log-path=/tmp/chromedriver.log'])
```

For me it worked.

Answer (score 7):

It is important on Win to set the name of chrome.exe otherwise it fail to create a process (see below):

```
  from selenium import webdriver
  from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

  options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
  options.binary_location = r"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"
  chrome_driver_binary = r"C:/Users/Max/.wdm/chromedriver/75.0.3770.8/win32/chromedriver.exe"
  driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_driver_binary, chrome_options=options)
  driver.get('http://web.whatsapp.com')
```

selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Failed to create a Chrome process.

For Firefox (download driver https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases):

```
  options = webdriver.FirefoxOptions()
  #options.add_argument('-headless')
  #options.binary_location = r"C:\maxbook\maxboxpython\geckodriver-v0.24.0-win64\geckodriver.exe"
  options.binary_location = r"C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe"
  firefox_driver_binary = r"C:\maxbook\maxboxpython\geckodriver-v0.24.0-win64\\"
  driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_driver_binary, options=options)
```

Comment: good evening dear Max - well i wonder how to get this fix included in google-colab!? It is important for me to get a solution in google colab. How to do that!?

Comment: in colab you can use download as well with wget (with ! at the begin):
!wget https://github.com/maxkleiner/maXbox4/releases/download/V4.2.4.80/maxbox4.zip
#!sudo apt-get install unzip
!unzip maxbox4.zip
!ls -l

Comment: dear Max - many thanks for the answer and all your hints - i try to get the things up and running - see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76401453/gathering-data-from-clutch-io-some-issues-with-bs4-while-working-on-colab  - but untill now -  still struggle with all my approaches - look forward to hear from yiou. Regards

Answer (score 4):

In my case, I install the Chrome browser then it's not throwing an error.

Comment: Hi there - many thanks for the hint. I am trying to do so

Comment: @what command did you use to install the browser?

Answer (score 3):

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.binary_location = r"<YOUR_CHROME_PATH>\chrome.exe"
chrome_driver_path = r"<PATH_TO_CHROME_DRIVER>\chromedriver.exe>"

browser = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_driver_path, chrome_options=options)
```

Comment: More explanation would be helpful for the OP.

Comment: @Kyle Mar see bellow please.

Answer (score 2):

If your `chromedriver` is located within `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/` directory the following code block should be working for you:

```
from selenium import webdriver

chrome_path = r'/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/chromedriver'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=chrome_path)
driver.get('https://www.google.co.in')
```

Comment: well dear undeteched Selenium - many thanks - i am trying to get this solution working for me.

Comment: hello dear undetected Selenium - first of all many many thanks for your ciontinued help in all that things: dear u. Selenium: again many thanks for the answer and all your hints - i try to get the things up and running - see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76401453/gathering-data-from-clutch-io-some-issues-with-bs4-while-working-on-colab  - but untill now -  still struggle with all my approaches - look forward to hear from yiou. Regards

Answer (score 1):

all you need is download latest version of chrome and chromedriver and install
it

Answer (score 0):

This [article](https://thecomputernoob.com/2020/09/24/selenium-cannot-find-chrome-binary-error/) gives the full breakdown on what is happening. Installing the latest web driver should fix the problem rather than changing the code.

Basically version 85 of chrome was installed in a different location, however this only affected new installations so it wasn't noticeable for most people.

The latest web driver understands about the new location so getting an updated driver is the easiest solution - that is of course unless you specifically need to test an older version.

[Location of drivers.](https://chromedriver.chromium.org/)

Answer (score 0):

I recently solved this issue by simply downloading the *Chrome Browser*. Download it and to download latest version of chrome driver by using this code

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
```

Answer (score 0):

Create file `main.py` has content

```py
from selenium import webdriver

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.binary_location = r"C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"
chrome_driver_binary = r"C:/Users/firerose/Downloads/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_driver_binary, options=options)
driver.get('https://golangnow.com')
```

Notice: New keyword is `options` .

Releated links

- https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/114.0.5735.16/chromedriver_win32.zip
- https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=114.0.5735.16/
- https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads
- https://github.com/SergeyPirogov/webdriver_manager
- https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/index.html

Answer (score -1):

For mac:
Note space between **Chrome** and **.app**

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.binary_location = "/Applications/Google Chrome .app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome"
chrome_driver_binary = "/usr/local/bin/chromedriver"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_driver_binary, chrome_options=options)
```