# how to run chromedriver on aws python

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, selenium, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

I am using selenium to scrape and below code works locally with a local path. I'm getting WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: cannot find Chrome binary. I am not sure I'm getting this error because my path is wrong or I have to install something? I been on google for many hours trying to figure this out but no luck.. please help!!

```
chrome_path = "/home/ec2-user/chrome/chromedriver"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_path)

book_categories_list = []
for i in asin:
    try:
        url = u"https://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss?url=search-alias%3Dstripbooks&field-keywords="+str(i)
        driver.get(url)
        #time.sleep(1)
        books = driver.find_element_by_class_name('a-expander-container') 
        book_categories_list.append(books.text)
    except:
        book_categories_list.append('Unknown') 

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
WebDriverException                        Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-436f3e3e0dac> in <module>()
      1 # Set driver and chrome driver path
      2 chrome_path = "/home/ec2-user/chrome/chromedriver"
----> 3 driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_path)
      4 
      5 # Url that I will access to scrape

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py in __init__(self, executable_path, port, options, service_args, desired_capabilities, service_log_path, chrome_options)
     73                 command_executor=ChromeRemoteConnection(
     74                     remote_server_addr=self.service.service_url),
---> 75                 desired_capabilities=desired_capabilities)
     76         except Exception:
     77             self.quit()

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py in __init__(self, command_executor, desired_capabilities, browser_profile, proxy, keep_alive, file_detector, options)
    152             warnings.warn("Please use FirefoxOptions to set browser profile",
    153                           DeprecationWarning)
--> 154         self.start_session(desired_capabilities, browser_profile)
    155         self._switch_to = SwitchTo(self)
    156         self._mobile = Mobile(self)

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py in start_session(self, capabilities, browser_profile)
    241         parameters = {"capabilities": w3c_caps,
    242                       "desiredCapabilities": capabilities}
--> 243         response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
    244         if 'sessionId' not in response:
    245             response = response['value']

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py in execute(self, driver_command, params)
    310         response = self.command_executor.execute(driver_command, params)
    311         if response:
--> 312             self.error_handler.check_response(response)
    313             response['value'] = self._unwrap_value(
    314                 response.get('value', None))

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py in check_response(self, response)
    240                 alert_text = value['alert'].get('text')
    241             raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace, alert_text)
--> 242         raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
    243 
    244     def _value_or_default(self, obj, key, default):

WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: cannot find Chrome binary
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.37.544315 (730aa6a5fdba159ac9f4c1e8cbc59bf1b5ce12b7),platform=Linux 4.9.81-35.56.amzn1.x86_64 x86_64)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Selenium gives "selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: cannot find Chrome binary" on Mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46026987/selenium-gives-selenium-common-exceptions-webdriverexception-message-unknown)

Comment: I dont understand what you mean by that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error does gives us the hint as follows :

```
WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: cannot find Chrome binary
```

The error essentially means *ChromeDriver* didn't find the *Chrome* binary in the expected location.

There can be two solutions as follows :

- As per the [Requirements](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/ChromeDriver#requirements) the *Chrome* installation needs to be in a definite location.
- As an alternative you can pass the *absolute path* of the *Chrome* binary through an instance of `Options` class as follows :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

  options = Options()
  options.binary_location = "/Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome"
  ```
- Finally while initiating the *WebDriver* and *WebClient* you need to send the argument *Key* **executable_path** along with the *Value* **chrome_path**.

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

  options = Options()
  options.binary_location = "/Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome"
  chrome_path = "/home/ec2-user/chrome/chromedriver"
  driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=chrome_path, chrome_options=options)
  ```

Comment: Check out my answer update and let me know the status.

Comment: I'm getting WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: no chrome binary at /Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome error

Comment: @JakePark Check the location of _chrome_ binary within your system and pass the _absolute path_ as a value to `options.binary_location`

Comment: Now im getting this error I think im going somewhere WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally

Comment: @JakePark Great News !!! So your actual error `WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: cannot find Chrome binary` is resolved. Can you raise a new question with your new requirement please?

Comment: Your answer actually didn't help but I'll upvote incase it might help someone else