# selenium -> chromedriver.exe ->Message: unknown error: cannot find Chrome binary

Tags: selenium-chromedriver

Please help me. I want to start module webdriver from selenium and use chromedriver.exe on windows.

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time

# driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='D:\download\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe')
```

After execute simple code:

```
 Message: unknown error: cannot find Chrome binary
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Selenium gives "selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: cannot find Chrome binary" on Mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46026987/selenium-gives-selenium-common-exceptions-webdriverexception-message-unknown)

Answer (score 0):

I used this code and import is to update chrome to Version 87.0.4280.88 (Official Build) (32-bit) because after open browse get error "Getting Radio failed" and could not use "driver.close()"

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--remote-debugging-port=9222")
options.binary_location = "D:\\download\\GoogleChromePortable2\\GoogleChromePortable.exe"
chrome_driver_path = "D:\\download\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver87.exe"

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=chrome_driver_path, options=options)

driver.get('https:/python.org')

time.sleep(13)

driver.close()
```