# Selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: no chrome binary

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to run a python script I made a few months ago which uses selenium to scrape a web page. Here's my code:

```
import pandas as pd
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="/users/aliallam/Documents/chromedriver")
```

Here's the full error I'm getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/aliallam/Desktop/MISOS_Python_Scraper/main.py", line 16, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="/users/aliallam/Documents/chromedriver")
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 76, in __init__
    RemoteWebDriver.__init__(
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 157, in __init__
    self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 252, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: cannot find Chrome binary
```

I tried the solution under this question, but still no luck: [Selenium gives "selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: cannot find Chrome binary" on Mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46026987/selenium-gives-selenium-common-exceptions-webdriverexception-message-unknown)

Here's what I changed my code to:

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.binary_location = " /Applications/Google\ Chrome\ 2.app"
chrome_driver_binary = "/users/aliallam/Documents/chromedriver"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_driver_binary,chrome_options=options)
```

This is really frustrating, some help would be much appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Comment: It looks like you might have added an extra space in your binary location, try taking that out and rerunning your code: `options.binary_location = "/Applications/Google\ Chrome\ 2.app"` (the extra space is located after the first quotation mark)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT: In addition to the following mistake, I think you also need to change the binary location to be `/Applications/Google Chrome 2.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome`

Based on what you posted, I think the error is because of an extra space located after the first quotation mark in this line:

```
options.binary_location = " /Applications/Google\ Chrome\ 2.app"
```

Try changing that to:

```
options.binary_location = "/Applications/Google Chrome 2.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome"
```

and rerunning the code.

Full code based on what you provided:

```
from selenium import webdriver

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.binary_location = "/Applications/Google Chrome 2.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome"
chrome_driver_binary = "/users/aliallam/Documents/chromedriver"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_driver_binary,chrome_options=options)
```

If that doesn't work, you could also try

```
from selenium import webdriver

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.binary_location = "/Applications/Google Chrome 2.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome"
executable_path = "/users/aliallam/Documents/chromedriver"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=executable_path, chrome_options=options)
```

Comment: Thanks! Removing the space didn't work, but the other code you wrote did.

Answer (score 0):

For me on MacOS the error got solved when I moved my downloaded "Google Chrome" application from "Downloads" folder to "Applications" Folder