# Nightwatch.js doesn't work on Linux server

Tags: selenium, jenkins, selenium-chromedriver, nightwatch.js, end-to-end

**I edited the question.**

If someone can help me to understand why my test doesn't work, it would be very appreciated.

It seems to me that Selenium server starts and Chromedriver starts (please take a look at 'selenium-debug.log' section), but tests scripts are not executed.

My codes work on my Mac, but I don't know why they don't on a Linux server.

My codes are here: https://github.com/watarumohawk/nightwatchjs-e2e

On the server, node is v7.2.0, and npm is v4.0.5. So I installed these versions on my Mac, but I still can't reproduce the issue on my Mac.

On my Mac, 'npm run test:amazon' and 'node_modules/nightwatch/bin/nightwatch' work.

On the Linux server, I tried this:

#### node_modules/nightwatch/bin/nightwatch

```
$ node_modules/nightwatch/bin/nightwatch
Starting selenium server in parallel mode... started - PID:  29825
Started child process for: amazon/amazon-top
  >> amazon/amazon-top finished.
```

#### npm run test:amazon

```
    $ npm run test:amazon

    > Nightwatch-e2e@1.1.0 test:amazon /home/foo/work/hoge/nightwatchjs-e2e
    > nightwatch --group amazon

    Starting selenium server in parallel mode... started - PID:  30066

    Started child process for: amazon/amazon-top

      >> amazon/amazon-top finished.



    npm ERR! Linux 3.10.0-327.4.5.el7.x86_64
    npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "run" "test:amazon"
    npm ERR! node v7.2.0
    npm ERR! npm  v4.0.5
    npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
    npm ERR! Nightwatch-e2e@1.1.0 test:amazon: `nightwatch --group amazon`
    npm ERR! Exit status 1
    npm ERR!
    npm ERR! Failed at the Nightwatch-e2e@1.1.0 test:amazon script 'nightwatch --group amazon'.
    npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
    npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the Nightwatch-e2e package,
    npm ERR! not with npm itself.
    npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
    npm ERR!     nightwatch --group amazon
    npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
    npm ERR!     npm bugs Nightwatch-e2e
    npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
    npm ERR!     npm owner ls Nightwatch-e2e
    npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

    npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
    npm ERR!     /home/foo/work/hoge/nightwatchjs-e2e/npm-debug.log
```

## Settings:

#### package.json

```
{
  ...... 

  "scripts": {
    "test": "nightwatch",
    "test:amazon": "nightwatch --group amazon"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "chai-nightwatch": "^0.1.1",
    "chromedriver": "^2.32.3",
    "nightwatch": "^0.9.16",
    "selenium-server-standalone-jar": "3.6.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {}
}
```

#### nightwatch.json

```
{
    "src_folders" : ["tests"],
    "output_folder" : "reports",
    "custom_commands_path" : "",
    "custom_assertions_path" : "",
    "page_objects_path" : "",
    "globals_path" : "",
    "test_workers" : {"enabled" : true, "workers" : "auto"},
    "selenium" : {
        "start_process" : true,
        "server_path" : "node_modules/selenium-server-standalone-jar/jar/selenium-server-standalone-3.6.0.jar",
        "log_path" : "",
        "host" : "127.0.0.1",
        "port" : 4444,
        "cli_args" : {
          "webdriver.chrome.driver" : "node_modules/chromedriver/lib/chromedriver/chromedriver",
          "webdriver.ie.driver" : ""
        }
    },
    "test_settings" : {
        "default" : {
            "launch_url" : "http://localhost",
            "selenium_port"  : 4444,
            "selenium_host"  : "localhost",
            "silent": true,
            "firefox_profile": false,
            "chrome_driver" : "",
            "screenshots" : {
                "enabled" : true,
                "path" : "screenshots",
                "on_failure": true,
                "on_error": false
            },
            "desiredCapabilities": {
                "browserName": "chrome",
                "javascriptEnabled": true,
                "acceptSslCerts": true,
                "chromeOptions": {
                    "args": ["--headless","--window-size=1920,1080"]
                },
                "use_xpath": false
            }
        }
    }
}
```

## Logs:

#### selenium-debug.log

```
    15:31:22.180 INFO - Selenium build info: version: '3.6.0', revision: '6fbf3ec767'
    15:31:22.180 INFO - Launching a standalone Selenium Server
    2017-10-19 15:31:22.193:INFO::main: Logging initialized @159ms to org.seleniumhq.jetty9.util.log.StdErrLog
    15:31:22.228 INFO - Driver class not found: com.opera.core.systems.OperaDriver
    15:31:22.247 INFO - Driver provider class org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver registration is skipped:
     registration capabilities Capabilities [{ensureCleanSession=true, browserName=internet explorer, version=, platform=WINDOWS}] does not match the current platform LINUX
    15:31:22.247 INFO - Driver provider class org.openqa.selenium.edge.EdgeDriver registration is skipped:
     registration capabilities Capabilities [{browserName=MicrosoftEdge, version=, platform=WINDOWS}] does not match the current platform LINUX
    15:31:22.247 INFO - Driver provider class org.openqa.selenium.safari.SafariDriver registration is skipped:
     registration capabilities Capabilities [{browserName=safari, version=, platform=MAC}] does not match the current platform LINUX
    15:31:22.264 INFO - Using the passthrough mode handler
    2017-10-19 15:31:22.281:INFO:osjs.Server:main: jetty-9.4.5.v20170502
    2017-10-19 15:31:22.297:WARN:osjs.SecurityHandler:main: ServletContext@o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@eec5a4a{/,null,STARTING} has uncovered http methods for path: /
    2017-10-19 15:31:22.300:INFO:osjsh.ContextHandler:main: Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@eec5a4a{/,null,AVAILABLE}
    2017-10-19 15:31:22.310:INFO:osjs.AbstractConnector:main: Started ServerConnector@9660f4e{HTTP/1.1,[http/1.1]}{0.0.0.0:4444}
    2017-10-19 15:31:22.311:INFO:osjs.Server:main: Started @278ms
    15:31:22.311 INFO - Selenium Server is up and running
    2017-10-19 15:31:22.528:INFO:osjshC.ROOT:qtp1910163204-11: org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.WebDriverServlet-28d25987: Initialising WebDriverServlet
    15:31:22.552 INFO - Binding default provider to: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService
    15:31:22.553 INFO - Found handler: org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.commandhandler.BeginSession@41c87be0
    15:31:22.555 INFO - /session: Executing POST on /session (handler: BeginSession)
    15:31:22.587 INFO - Capabilities are: Capabilities {acceptSslCerts=true, name=Amazon / Amazon Top, browserName=chrome, javascriptEnabled=true, use_xpath=false, chromeOptions={args=[--headless, --window-size=1920,1080]}, platformName=ANY, platform=ANY, }
    15:31:22.587 INFO - Capabilities {acceptSslCerts=true, name=Amazon / Amazon Top, browserName=chrome, javascriptEnabled=true, use_xpath=false, chromeOptions={args=[--headless, --window-size=1920,1080]}, platformName=ANY, platform=ANY, } matched class org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.ServicedSession$Factory (provider: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService)
    15:31:22.588 INFO - Capabilities {acceptSslCerts=true, name=Amazon / Amazon Top, browserName=chrome, javascriptEnabled=true, use_xpath=false, chromeOptions={args=[--headless, --window-size=1920,1080]}, platformName=ANY, platform=ANY, } matched class org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.ServicedSession$Factory (provider: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService)
    15:31:22.588 INFO - Capabilities {acceptSslCerts=true, name=Amazon / Amazon Top, browserName=chrome, javascriptEnabled=true, use_xpath=false, chromeOptions={args=[--headless, --window-size=1920,1080]}, platformName=ANY, platform=ANY, } matched class org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.ServicedSession$Factory (provider: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService)
    Starting ChromeDriver 2.33.506092 (733a02544d189eeb751fe0d7ddca79a0ee28cce4) on port 27120
    Only local connections are allowed.
```

#### npm-debug.log

```
    0 info it worked if it ends with ok
    1 verbose cli [ '/usr/local/bin/node',
    1 verbose cli   '/usr/local/bin/npm',
    1 verbose cli   'run',
    1 verbose cli   'test:amazon' ]
    2 info using npm@4.0.5
    3 info using node@v7.2.0
    4 verbose run-script [ 'pretest:amazon', 'test:amazon', 'posttest:amazon' ]
    5 info lifecycle Nightwatch-e2e@1.1.0~pretest:amazon: Nightwatch-e2e@1.1.0
    6 silly lifecycle Nightwatch-e2e@1.1.0~pretest:amazon: no script for pretest:amazon, continuing
    7 info lifecycle Nightwatch-e2e@1.1.0~test:amazon: Nightwatch-e2e@1.1.0
    8 verbose lifecycle Nightwatch-e2e@1.1.0~test:amazon: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
    9 verbose lifecycle Nightwatch-e2e@1.1.0~test:amazon: PATH: /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/node-gyp-bin:/home/foo/work/hoge/nightwatchjs-e2e/node_modules/.bin:/home/foo/.pyenv/shims:/home/foo/.pyenv/bin:/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin:/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/home/foo/.local/bin:/home/foo/bin
    10 verbose lifecycle Nightwatch-e2e@1.1.0~test:amazon: CWD: /home/foo/work/hoge/nightwatchjs-e2e
    11 silly lifecycle Nightwatch-e2e@1.1.0~test:amazon: Args: [ '-c', 'nightwatch --group amazon' ]
    12 silly lifecycle Nightwatch-e2e@1.1.0~test:amazon: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
    13 info lifecycle Nightwatch-e2e@1.1.0~test:amazon: Failed to exec test:amazon script
    14 verbose stack Error: Nightwatch-e2e@1.1.0 test:amazon: `nightwatch --group amazon`
    14 verbose stack Exit status 1
    14 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/lifecycle.js:279:16)
    14 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
    14 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:191:7)
    14 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/spawn.js:40:14)
    14 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
    14 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)
    14 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:885:16)
    14 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:226:5)
    15 verbose pkgid Nightwatch-e2e@1.1.0
    16 verbose cwd /home/foo/work/hoge/nightwatchjs-e2e
    17 error Linux 3.10.0-327.4.5.el7.x86_64
    18 error argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "run" "test:amazon"
    19 error node v7.2.0
    20 error npm  v4.0.5
    21 error code ELIFECYCLE
    22 error Nightwatch-e2e@1.1.0 test:amazon: `nightwatch --group amazon`
    22 error Exit status 1
    23 error Failed at the Nightwatch-e2e@1.1.0 test:amazon script 'nightwatch --group amazon'.
    23 error Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
    23 error If you do, this is most likely a problem with the Nightwatch-e2e package,
    23 error not with npm itself.
    23 error Tell the author that this fails on your system:
    23 error     nightwatch --group amazon
    23 error You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
    23 error     npm bugs Nightwatch-e2e
    23 error Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
    23 error     npm owner ls Nightwatch-e2e
    23 error There is likely additional logging output above.
    24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Comment: Just a guess, is Nightwatch in your PATH on your Mac but not on your Linux box?  I see that by hand you run `node_modules/nightwatch/bin/nightwatch` but from package.json you it's just `nightwatch`.  Does it work if you use the full path to the nightwatch binary in package.json?

Comment: On both of Mac and Linux, I don't install nightdatch as global. I just do git clone my [repo](https://github.com/watarumohawk/nightwatchjs-e2e) and run it. That's why I do `node_modules/nightwatch/bin/nightwatch` on Mac and Linux to investigate. The result should be the same. But on Linux, the result is

```
$ node_modules/nightwatch/bin/nightwatch
Starting selenium server in parallel mode... started - PID:  11704

Started child process for: amazon/amazon-top

  >> amazon/amazon-top finished.
```

Comment: Try also removing the `test_workers` config.  Nightwatch outputs less error detail when tests are in parallel.

Comment: I found out that I needed to install Chrome as George mentioned on this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43287203/selenium-gives-unknown-error-cannot-find-chrome-binary-when-running-chrome-dr